# RegularExpression for getting the link inside particular tag

Tags: c#, regex

```
some text <a href="https://sample.com"</a>some text
<p> some text1 <a href="https://example1.com"</a></p>
<p> some text 2<a href="https://example2.com"</a></p>
<p> some text 3<a href="https://example3.com"</a></p>
some text <a href="https://sample.com"</a>some text
```

I have a string like this. I need to get the links inside the `<p>` tag only. I need to use a regular expression to parse this string.

Comment: Your links are improperly formatted. Perhaps previous solutions you've tried have run into this problem.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML, use HTML parser instead.

Comment: Do you specifically have to use Regular Expressions? you could use a jquery selector like: 'p > a'

Answer (score 2):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bU7jT/1/), uses JQuery Selectors like this:

```
var paragraphNestedLinks = $('p >a');
paragraphNestedLinks.each(function(index, value){
alert(value); 
 });​
```

*This example will just show each of the 3 links nested in a paragraph in an alert box.*

You will also need to fix your HTML. The links are not well formed. See below:

```
some text <a href="https://sample.com">Link Text</a>some text
<p> some text1 <a href="https://example1.com">Link Text</a></p>
<p> some text 2<a href="https://example2.com">Link Text</a></p>
<p> some text 3<a href="https://example3.com">Link Text</a></p>
some text <a href="https://sample.com">Link Text</a>some text​
```